# SQL UPDATE Command - How can i tell how many records have been updated?

Tags: sql

If i have a SQL statement like:

```
Update people
set people_name = "rambo"
where people = "Terminator"
```

How can I show how many records have been updated? Is it possible?

Comment: It is different for each database system. You need to specify

Answer (score 2):

Use @@rowcount: `SELECT @@rowcount AS 'RowsChanged'`

http://www.brettb.com/SQL_Help_Rowcount_Rows_Affected.asp

Answer (score 0):

you can use @@rowcount

> Update people set people_name =
>   "rambo" where people = "Terminator"
>
> SELECT @@rowcount AS 'RowsAffected'

Edit - you can use @@rowcount if you are using SQL Server